# buffer overflow detected in mariadb 10.3.11

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.7, bulk-insert, buffer-pool, mariadb-10.3

We are getting Assertion failure every time memory usage of MySQL spikes up to the overall system's memory.

Example:

> InnoDB: Assertion failure in file
>    /home/buildbot/buildbot/build/mariadb-10.3.11/storage/innobase/btr/btr0sea.cc line 1415
>
> InnoDB: Failing assertion: index->id == btr_page_get_index_id(page)

along with below error in stack trace,

```
Server version: 10.3.11-MariaDB-1:10.3.11+maria~xenial-log
key_buffer_size=536870912
read_buffer_size=10485760
max_used_connections=42
max_threads=302
thread_count=46
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 65473079 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f17100009a8
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7f171e379b78 thread_stack 0x49000
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/sbin/mysqld terminated
```

Every time Assertion failure reports different file in code location "/home/buildbot/buildbot/build/mariadb-10.3.11/storage", but every time we see the same buffer overflow detected statement in the mysqld log.

I've attached stack trace as well my.cnf file.

We are having below server with hardware configuration,

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Memory: 72G
No. of Cores: 36

**Our Scenario**: We're inserting about 30 million records for one ETL, we have 4 ETL jobs running and using same MySQL Instance to write. batch size: 50k

We have a few suspects, but still, we are unable to get convinced those were the issue,

1. Ideally, We are inserting about 100m records with "on duplicate key update". - Are these inserts possible to load all related indexes back into memory as pages(young/non-young pages) and it's not clearing??
2. I was trying to insert same 50k inserts for about 2m records, I see, there was memory spike about to 2%(based on data size), every time I run it, again and again, it gets added up, but not releasing it

Important: when we see this issue, table data also getting corrupted. we left with no choice other than using a backup to start MySQL instance again. That's our huge worries for now.

> [*Updates added recently to this content on 31st May'19]
>
> There was an existing bug regarding not closing the connection
>   properly, on our code and we fixed it, which stabilized our memory way
>   better. still, we are seeing utilization memory continues.*

**my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

server-id       = 1
pid-file        = /data/db/datadir/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0

binlog_format   = ROW
binlog_row_image= minimal

log-bin
log-basename    = rs-bin
expire_logs_days = 1

datadir         = /data/db/datadir/
tmpdir          = /data/db/mysql_tmp
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log

#user           = mysql
###basedir      = /usr

#innodb_force_recovery = 1

symbolic-links=0

log_slave_updates
sync_binlog=0
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
slow_query_log=ON

transaction-isolation=READ-UNCOMMITTED

max_connections                 = 300
max_allowed_packet              = 100M
net_buffer_length               = 4M
net_read_timeout                = 300
net_write_timeout               = 360
query_cache_type                = 0
sort_buffer_size                = 200M
key_buffer_size                 = 512M
tmp_table_size                  = 1073741824
max_sort_length                 = 2048
max_heap_table_size             = 1G
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1

aria-pagecache-buffer-size      = 3G
#aria-block-size                = 4096

innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 40G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 40
innodb_log_file_size            = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 128M
innodb_log_compressed_pages     = off
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_file_per_table           = ON
innodb_thread_sleep_delay       = 10000
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 0
innodb_write_io_threads         = 64 #2x of cores
innodb_read_io_threads          = 64 #2x of cores
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 50
innodb_io_capacity              = 10000# benchmark and change
innodb_io_capacity_max          = 20000
innodb_sort_buffer_size         = 10M  #perthread buffer
innodb_spin_wait_delay          = 3  #half the standard value
innodb_old_blocks_pct           = 20
innodb_old_blocks_time          = 1000
innodb_page_cleaners            = 64
innodb_print_all_deadlocks      = ON
innodb_purge_threads            = 1
innodb_flush_neighbors          = 0 #good for ssds
innodb_flush_sync               = true
innodb_use_native_aio           = true
innodb_random_read_ahead        = true
innodb_checksum_algorithm       = crc32

#need to tune this based on performance of DML queries, max of 5000 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-improved-purge-scheduling.html
innodb_purge_batch_size         = 2000

#Parameters synced from RDS
back_log                        = 900
###binlog_annotate_row_events   = OFF
binlog_checksum                 = NONE
general_log                     = OFF
general_log_file                = /var/log/mysql-general.log
group_concat_max_len            = 1024
host_cache_size                 = 1114
innodb_lock_schedule_algorithm  = fcfs
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  = 0.001

innodb_strict_mode              = OFF
innodb_use_atomic_writes        = OFF
read_buffer_size                = 10485760
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 52428800
relay_log_recovery              = ON
open_files_limit                = 65535

#innodb_purge_threads           = 1
#innodb_spin_wait_delay         = 6
#sql_mode                       = 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
###thread_cache_size            = 0
###thread_pool_max_threads      = 1000
###thread_pool_size             = 16
#optimizer_switch               = 'orderby_uses_equalities=off,condition_pushdown_for_derived=off,split_materialized=off'


# A setting smaller than the default is generally suitable for most workloads. A value that is much higher than necessary may impact performance. Only consider increasing the value if you have spare I/O capacity under a typical workload. Conversely, if a write-intensive workload saturates your I/O capacity, decrease the value, especially in the case of a large buffer pool.

innodb_lru_scan_depth           = 2048

###innodb_monitor_enable        = 'all'
#innodb_page_size               = 4096 #same as amazon i3 blocksize for optimized ssd writes
#innodb_thread_sleep_delay_max  = 20000


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
pid-file=/data/db/datadir/mysqld.pid
```

**Stack Trace:** (Couldn't upload rest of it, but rest of it, are just memory mapping details,

```
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.3.11-MariaDB-1:10.3.11+maria~xenial-log
key_buffer_size=536870912
read_buffer_size=10485760
max_used_connections=42
max_threads=302
thread_count=46
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 65473079 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f17100009a8
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7f171e379b78 thread_stack 0x49000
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/sbin/mysqld terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f2282f887e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7f228302a15c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x117160)[0x7f2283028160]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x1190a7)[0x7f228302a0a7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_addr_resolve+0xde)[0x5646f87a6c6e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x1e2)[0x5646f878b092]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x347)[0x5646f8239687]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f2283977390]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7f2282f46428]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7f2282f4802a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x49980a)[0x5646f7f8080a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xb1b2a0)[0x5646f86022a0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xb1baee)[0x5646f8602aee]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xb111ef)[0x5646f85f81ef]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa76fe2)[0x5646f855dfe2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa790d1)[0x5646f85600d1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa733e7)[0x5646f855a3e7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa761ac)[0x5646f855d1ac]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa7699d)[0x5646f855d99d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xa30ef9)[0x5646f8517ef9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xabec24)[0x5646f85a5c24]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xaa0b26)[0x5646f8587b26]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7f228396d6ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f228301841d]
======= Memory map: ========
5646f7ae7000-5646f8d49000 r-xp 00000000 103:03 51127                     /usr/sbin/mysqld
5646f8f49000-5646f9039000 r--p 01262000 103:03 51127                     /usr/sbin/mysqld
5646f9039000-5646f90f2000 rw-p 01352000 103:03 51127                     /usr/sbin/mysqld
5646f90f2000-5646f9989000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
5646fa098000-5647440b3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f0fe0000000-7f0fe3f39000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0fe3f39000-7f0fe4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 [Added]
7f0fe8000000-7f0fe8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 ...
```

Comment: There is a dbgsym package for this mariadb version. Do you have a core file generated? I can't see anything in the 10.3.12-10.3.15 release notes about an assert at this location. Probably worth writing a bug report https://jira.mariadb.org/

Comment: @danblack, I have raised a bug in jira.mariadb.org already, https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19450 - still haven't got any response. 


I haven't used any short of dbgsym package. I will look into related and update you. 

We are able to reproduce this issue by running more queries and when memory shoots up to physical memory then MySQL crashes with an above log.

for a workaround, we are restarting MySQL when it spikes up to 80-90% and then continuing our jobs.  Problem is we need to do babysit most of the time.

Comment: ok. Never seen anyone use `transaction-isolation=READ-UNCOMMITTED`, especially under load, as a guess that might be a cause.

Comment: Further to transaction isolation, transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED would seem safer if your doing IODKU where concurrent batches are updating the same rows. An `ON DUPLICATE KEY` update that depends on the same row would need to read and commit before another statement reads the same base original data otherwise the results of one of the statements will be discarded depending which does the actual update first.

Comment: @danblack, regarding `transaction-isolation`, it helps for SELECT right?
 We're not at all doing a SELECT while doing these assessments.

Comment: okay. I can correlate that with `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, let me try with this and keep posted.
Still, I doubt that it will improve/release memory usage

Comment: @danblack, I don't experience much effect on a change you suggested. 

There was an existing bug regarding not closing the connection properly, on our code and we fixed it, which stabilized our memory way better. still, we are seeing utlization memory continues. - I will update this in the main discussion content.